# Input in html to java file

Tags: java, html, input

I need an input in my html file (I think via javascript) and I need to parse in my Java file.

To get user input in html, it's easy, but I don't know how to parse in my java file.

Any suggestions or tutorials? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) like this.

```
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083471/input-in-html-to-java-file";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
System.out.println("title: " + doc.select("title").text());
System.out.println("users:");
for (Element e : doc.select("div.user-details a"))
    System.out.println("    " + e.text());
```

This code parse this page and print title and user names.

result:

```
title: Input in html to java file - Stack Overflow
users:
    l1den
    truekiller
    Ethan Three
    saka1029
```

Answer (score 0):

Ceate a form in html and when you submit call a servlet to handle the request. In servlet receive the value you want to handle by using `request.getParameter(name)` . There are many framework for `web MVC` like struts2 , spring MVC .

Comment: Thank you truekiller for answer, but I need more details, because I'm a beginner. I'm working with spring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are way many way to do it.
The simplest apporach is using html form,  your html should include javascript that is able to submit a form (the data from user) to server (POST to an url) as a request.

and then server should program to response the request (the url you submit to).

and then you pickup a framework (serverlet is simple one, but if you have an existing project, check how it process form data).

Comment: Thank you Ehthan for answer, but I need more details, because I'm a beginner. I'm working with spring.

Comment: Google spring mvc. There is a lot of stuff on the internet. Watch couple of example and then you will be able to achieve what you want.